# Create column based on rows of dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame. I'm trying to create a dummy variable that is the maximum of 3 columns for a given row.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  data[i,]$max_metric <- max(data[i,]$a,
                             data[i,]$b,
                             data[i,]$c)
}
```

This code works, but it's definitely not the best way to do it. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pmax`, which takes the element-wise maximum of all arguments passed to it.  However, this means you can't just pass the whole data.frame.

```
# this won't work because data[,c("a","b","c")] is one argument
data$max_metric <- pmax(data[,c("a","b","c")])
```

But you can pass each column of the data.frame to `pmax` via `do.call` because the second argument to `do.call` should be a list and data.frames are lists (with some attributes).

```
data$max_metric <- do.call(pmax, data[,c("a","b","c")])
# if you want na.rm=TRUE
data$max_metric <- do.call(pmax, c(data[,c("a","b","c")],list(na.rm=TRUE)))
```